# Infinispan 5.3.0 - Change cluster configuration

Tags: configuration, cluster-computing, infinispan

I've a cluster, this cluster has four nodes.

If I stop one node, and edit the configuration file (add a new replicated cache), 
When I'll start the node,

- Will the cluster have the new replicated cache?
- In the others three nodes, is it necessary change the configuration file?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

a) Yes, the new replicated cache will be created on the node. However, if you have the same cache (name) with different configurations, you're asking for trouble.

b) No, the configuration on other nodes will not change. You have to change it manually, either stopping the nodes, or running rolling upgrade.

You may also look into JMX operations for starting/stopping cache, but this does not allow to change the configuration (I am not 100% sure if starting a cache with unknown name wouldn't start a new cache with default configuration).
If you have programmatic access to CacheManager, you can start cache with configuration provided programmatically.